# Extracting string from any non-binary file irrespective of its location within file

Tags: batch-file

OK, here is a problem I have been unsuccessfully trying to cope with, writing a batch script. Suppose I have a file containing, say, some youtube addresses (for example a html file with links to youtube pages).

The content of the file may look like this:

```
Blaaaa blaa
blaa blaa blaa <a href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0>Gangnam1</a> blaaa blaa
<a href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYtGl1dX5qI&list=RD9bZkp7q19f0>Scream and shout</a> blaa blaa
blaaaaa <a href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWA2pjMjpBs&list=RD9bZkp7q19f0>Diamonds</a> blaa
blaa bla bla
```

The strings will be found using wildcard character mask, like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=*>
```

(or something of this kind)

And the output saved in another file should look as follows:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYtGl1dX5qI&list=RD9bZkp7q19f0>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWA2pjMjpBs&list=RD9bZkp7q19f0>
```

The search may of course regards also other strings, not only youtube related.

Simple commands like FIND or FINDSTR cannot be used, as they return the whole line containing the string. Similarly, FOR with tokens and delimiters seems to be of little use here, as the strings to be found are scattered irregularly all over the file, sometimes a few in the same line.

I really do not know how to solve this problem. It may seem simple, still I have never found a script or program that would give an output like that. Perhaps there even exists a ready, compiled program to do it. I will owe a lot for any help.

Comment: The answer by sachadee seems useful, and regular expressions using `repl.bat` can be another solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use another scripting language as Bat to do that. 
Here I made a little exemple in Autoit :

**StringBetween.au3**

```
#include <String.au3>
Local $hOutFile=FileOpen("output.txt",2)
Local $hTexte=FileRead($CmdLine[1])
$AFind=_StringBetween($hTexte,$cmdline[2],$cmdline[3])
For $i= 0 To UBound($Afind)-1 step 1
   FileWrite($hOutFile,$AFind[$i]&@crlf)
Next
FileClose($hOutFile)
```

You can compile it yourself or Download it already compiled here :

[StringBetween.rar](http://services.supportduweb.com/cptcl/link.php?id=10642385792951)

**Usage :**

Stringbetween [InPutFile] [StringRight] [StringLeft]

**Ouput :** "Output.txt"

In your case :

```
Stringbetween.exe "example.html" "<a href=" ">"
```

A file `"Output.txt"` will be created with :

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYtGl1dX5qI&list=RD9bZkp7q19f0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWA2pjMjpBs&list=RD9bZkp7q19f0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick response. It really helped a lot. I am impressed very much.

I have never used AutoIt and now I see it is a useful utility indeed! I have downloaded the program and had big fun trying it. I like the huge library of functions (although their being scattered all over various scripts makes them slightly messy and unintuitive to find) and particularly the ability to compile script code into executable files. I will certainly use it in future, too.

I have slightly modified your script, to be able to process many files from one directory at a time. This is what it looks like right now:

```
#include <String.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPIFiles.au3>

;Parameters:
Local $Ldelimiter, $Rdelimiter, $Filter, $Outputfilename

;Prompt for parameters if not stated in command line:
If $CmdLine[0] < 1 Then
$Ldelimiter=InputBox("","Enter the left delimiter :","") 
Else
   $Ldelimiter=$CmdLine[1]
   EndIf
If $CmdLine[0] < 2 Then
$Rdelimiter=InputBox("","Enter the right delimiter :","") 
Else
   $Rdelimiter=$CmdLine[2]
EndIf
If $CmdLine[0] < 3 Then
$Filter=InputBox("","Enter the filter mask :","*.*") 
Else
   $Filter=$CmdLine[3]
EndIf
If $CmdLine[0] < 4 Then
$Outputfilename=InputBox("","Enter the name of output file :","output.txt") 
Else
   $Outputfilename=$CmdLine[4]
EndIf

Local $hOutFile=FileOpen($Outputfilename,2) ;Open output file
Local $curpath=_WinAPI_GetCurrentDirectory()    ;Get current directory

Local $FileList=_FileListToArray($curpath,$Filter,1)    ;Make an array with the list of files to process

For $k= 1 To UBound($FileList)-1 step 1 ;Process a file from the list
    Local $hTexte=FileRead($FileList[$k])   ;Read file content
    $AFind=_StringBetween($hTexte,$Ldelimiter,$Rdelimiter)  ;Make an array with the list of strings to be found
    For $i= 0 To UBound($Afind)-1 step 1    ;Get a string from the list
        FileWrite($hOutFile,$Ldelimiter&$AFind[$i]&$Rdelimiter&@crlf)   ;Write the string to output file
    Next
Next
FileClose($hOutFile)

exit
```

**Usage:**

Stringbetween [StringLeft] [StringRight] [FileMask] [OutputFile]

If you fail to provide parameters in command line, the program will prompt for them. FileMask is *.* by default (all files in directory will be processed). I have also added the left and right delimiter to the output.

Regards

PS: I still wonder if it is possible to do the same with simple BAT.