# Get content of xml tags with batch file (UPDATED:Getting also tags attributes)

Tags: xml, parsing, batch-file

I have the following "file.xml":

```
<root>
<cities>
        <cityName>paris</cityName>
        <cityName>london</cityName>
        <cityName>...</cityName> 
        ...         
</cities>
<countries>
        <countryName>india</countryName>
        <countryName>japon</countryName> 
        <countryName>...</countryName>  
        ...         
</countries>
<continents>
        <continentName type="geo">asia</continentName>
        <continentName type="geo">america</continentName>
        <continentName type"geo">...</continentName>
        ...     
</continents>
</root>
```

I would like to get with a batch file all the content of a specified tag and also all the specified tag's attributes(key and value) and write in a file. For example, I specify "continentName" in my batch file, so I would have a "file.txt" with :
type geo asia
type geo america
type geo ...

This is what I have for the moment (I only get tags content, not attributes) :

```
@echo off    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set tag=continentName
set f_xml=file.xml

set tag2=/%tag%

for /f  "tokens=2-4delims=<>" %%a in (%f_xml%) do (
 IF "%%a"=="%tag%" IF "%%c"=="%tag2%" ECHO(%%b>>file.txt
)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried?

Comment: I add what I have on my first post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196417/extracting-string-from-any-non-binary-file-irrespective-of-its-location-within-f

Comment: Wow! You changed the question requirements, _including the title_, just like that? You should post a comment indicating this point at least!

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set tag=continentName
set f_xml=q23655846.txt

set tag2=/%tag%

for /f  "tokens=2-4delims=<>" %%a in (%f_xml%) do (
 IF "%%a"=="%tag%" IF "%%c"=="%tag2%" ECHO(%%b
)
GOTO :eof
```

This should get your output. I used a file named `q23655846.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Comment: Thank for your quick and effective answer. It works perfectly !

Comment: @Magoo any reason why you reverted my edit as it was perfectly answering the OP's question (same filename and output to text file)?

Comment: @katalin_2003: Been away a while, but at least I've got my tax returns done! There was nothing wrong with your changes, but I refuse to spoon-feed. Was cured of that when my solution in another forum was rejected (& rudely) because the OP expected a cut/paste solution & wasn't even prepared to replace `yourusername` with his user name & `yourpassword` with a sack of potatoes. I test the vast majority of my solutions using a batch named qSOquetionnumber.bat & use the same scheme for related fies. That way, if further questions occur, I can access the data without having to recreate `file1`

Comment: @Magoo Oh I understand, no harm done and thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: *Solution changed as reply to new specifications*

I changed the original Batch program to fulfill the *new* request:

```
@echo off
set tag=continentName
set f_xml=file.xml
(for /F "tokens=3,4 delims=<=>" %%a in ('findstr "\</%tag%\>" %f_xml%') do echo %%~a %%b) > file.txt
```

This program works *only* with the .xml file as shown above (I mean, at the moment I wrote this solution) and with this requested output:

```
geo asia
geo america
geo ...
```

If the file is changed (like inserting more attributes, or placing none attribute, or splitting the continentName tag in several lines, etc), or the output is changed, previous solution will not work.

Comment: It is bad ettiquete to change the requirements of a question. You want just the "type" attribute? May be more atttributes? How many? May be _none_ attribute (like in the first question)? We will not change our answers every time you change the question...

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure about what to do for this new request. As it was very close to my first question, I was hesitating about creating a new post.

Comment: If you change a question you should explain this point, at least! What about the other points I asked?

Comment: Done! Basically, I want for a specified tag, all the content and attributes.