# Extracting text in DOS to separate files

Tags: xml, batch-file, text, extract, doc

I'm interested in having a txt file parsed from word_A to word_B and the output sent to a new file ( new_file_1.txt)... Each time word_A and word_B are found within that original txt file the output is then pushed to new_file_2.txt +N...  and this continues

My goal is to extract txt between two xml tags and store the output into individual files...

thanks... I should mention the more detailed your response/help the better as I'm a novice.

Also can this be done in dos?  I have no compiler to run code...

Comment: This would be a tough slog in batch files.

Answer (score 0):

Tough, schmuff. Just needs to recycle old batches.

Really depends on your data format - but you haven't provided a sample.

[Here's one I solved earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655846)

Sample data in `q23655846.txt`

```
<root>
<cities>
        <cityName>paris</cityName>
        <cityName>london</cityName>
        <cityName>...</cityName> 
        ...         
</cities>
<countries>
        <countryName>india</countryName>
        <countryName>japon</countryName> 
        <countryName>...</countryName>  
        ...         
</countries>
<continents>
        <continentName>asia</continentName>
        <continentName>america</continentName>
        <continentName>South america</continentName>
        <continentName>...</continentName>
        ...     
</continents>
</root>
```

Modified code to suit the 'each in its own file` requirement:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "outloc=U:\destdir\file_"
set "tag=continentName"
set "f_xml=q23655846.txt"

set "tag2=/%tag%"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

set fcnt=0
for /f  "tokens=2-4delims=<>" %%a in (%f_xml%) do (
 IF "%%a"=="%tag%" IF "%%c"=="%tag2%" SET /a fcnt+=1&>>"%outloc%!fcnt!" ECHO(%%b
)
GOTO :eof
```

The setting of `outloc` I'll leave to you - the location I've posted is convenient for my system. Ditto the tag and xml filename.

Minor changes would be needed if you want to output a block or if your absolute sourcefile name contains separator characters like spaces.