# Read a XML input from a Batch file and store the values in a Variable, (fixed Json output to xml)

Tags: xml, batch-file, compare

I have been researching on how to read a xml input file into a batch file to read compare the data, but not had much luck.

This data will need then to be stored as a variable so we can compare the values.

There are a total of 4 values we need to measure, these are, temperature, ph, nh3 and o2

Because these values can change every hour when the data is pulled we need a way of comparing the data with a set value such as:

```
IF ph=7.8 GOTO PHHIGH ELSE OK
```

Is this possible?

Many thanks to all who responds.

I have included the xml file below:

http://s1.uploads.im/KriCJ.jpg

Comment: That is not an XML file

Comment: Isn't that a json file?

Comment: Hi, I was told this is a xml file by the suppler, but it does say they also support json format. Would it still be possible to use this as a input file?

Comment: Please edit your question. It does not make sense to talk about XML file but including a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

This works with the data you have now posted.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (temperature ph nh3 o2) do (
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=</>" %%b in ('type "[Megafileupload]Seneye_Reading.xml" ^|findrepl "(<.*?>.*?</.*?>)" "$1\r\n" ^|findrepl "><" ">\r\n<" ^|findrepl ".*<%%a>.*" /e:".*</%%a>.*" /b:".*<curr>" ') do set "123-%%a=%%b"
)
set 123
pause
```

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` (by aacini) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

Comment: Thanks foxidrive, I am getting a error when run,    Envriroment variable 123 not defined,    any ideas please?

Comment: The data that you have now posted doesn't have any line breaks.  Try the modified code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this :

```
@echo off
set $c=1
for /f  "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i  "curr" test.txt') do call:next "%%a"
echo ----
echo Temp = %temperature%
echo pH = %pH%
echo NH4 = %NH4%
echo O2 = %O2%
echo ---
if %pH% Geq 7.8 (echo   --^> The pH is High) else (echo   --^>The pH is OK)

exit /b

:next
set $Line=%1
set $Line=%$Line:<curr>=%
set $Line=%$Line:</curr>=%
set $Line=%$Line: =%
if %$c%==1 set temperature=%$Line:~1,-1%
if %$c%==2 set pH=%$Line:~1,-1%
if %$c%==3 set NH4=%$Line:~1,-1%
if %$c%==4 set O2=%$Line:~1,-1%
set /a $c+=1
```

Replace test.txt with the name of your file (.xml or .json).

This will get the values between `<curr></curr>`

**EDIT :**

Apparently your XML file is on one line.

You can use this small tool I made : [StringBetween.rar](http://services.supportduweb.com/cptcl/link.php?id=10642385792951%22%3EStringBetween.rar) for this POST : [Extracting string from any non-binary file irrespective of its location within file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196417/extracting-string-from-any-non-binary-file-irrespective-of-its-location-within-f/23198173#23198173)

Then your BAT file will look like this :

```
@echo off
set $c=1

stringbetween test.xml "<curr>" "</curr>"

for /f  "delims=" %%a in (output.txt) do call:next %%a
echo ----
echo Temp = %temperature%
echo pH = %pH%
echo NH3 = %NH3%
echo NH4 = %NH4%
echo O2 = %O2%
echo ---
if %pH% Geq 7.8 (echo   --^> The pH is High) else (echo   --^>The pH is OK)

exit /b

:next
echo %1

if %$c%==1 set temperature=%1
if %$c%==2 set pH=%1
if %$c%==3 set NH3=%1
if %$c%==4 set NH4=%1
if %$c%==5 set O2=%1
set /a $c+=1
```

Again : just replace `test.xml` by the name of your `xml` file.

Comment: Thanks you for response sachadee. I am getting this error when in a dos prompt      < was unexpected at this time.   Any iedas please?

Comment: can you post (copy/paste) your xml file in your post, that we can test the code in real.

Comment: i have tried to copy and paste the xml document but it does not display it correctly here, it shows     --0-124.9025.8-0-17.3507.25-1-10.02400.006--1-1122.29094.55-0-18.208.1-0-0-0    I have uploaded the xml document here;   http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/549468/Seneye-Reading-xml.html    Many Thanks

Comment: Your data has no line breaks - all the data is on one line.