# Extracting text from XML file via batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file, text-extraction

I have to extract certain text from an XML file via a batch file. One of the parts I need to extract is between string tags (`<string>example1</string>`) and the other is between data tags (`<data>example2</data>`). Any ideas how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196417/extracting-string-from-any-non-binary-file-irrespective-of-its-location-within-f/23198173#23198173

Comment: @sachadee It's not possible with a batch file?

Comment: @sachadee If not, how would I have to modify your "StringBetween.au3" script to accommodate my situation?

Comment: Which strings do you want to extract from the above line? example1 & example2?

Comment: You may consider using Windows Powershell for this as it natively supports an XML DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo OFF

del output.txt

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"<string>" xml_file.xml') do call     :job "%%i"
goto :eof

:job

set line=%1

set line=%line:/=%
set line=%line:<=+%
set line=%line:>=+%
set line=%line:*+string+=%
set line=%line:+=&rem.%
echo.%line%>>output.txt



:eof
```

Output with OP's input file-

```
D:\>draft.bat

D:\>type output.txt
000000000@gmail.com
default
Web form password
www.instagram.com (000000000@gmail.com)

www.instagram.com
```

Cheers, G

Comment: Thanks a lot!I think the script seems to have worked since no errors or anything emerged. However, is the output file supposed to be created in the same directory as the batch script? Because I can't find it.

Comment: I have modified the script to store the output in output.txt now. If it is working can you mark this as answer?

Comment: I ran the script and this is what was in the output file:

`string
string
data
string
string
stringstring
string
string
string
data
string
string
stringstring
string
string 
string 
data 
string 
string 
stringstring 
string`

Comment: OK. I'm not with my computer now and can't test it now. I can get it fixed in probably 8 hours from now. But o don't see any issues with the current code. Please ensure to not to miss any characters or not to add any extra spaces in my code.

Comment: This works absolutely fine with the above example file I used. Have you tried with the above example file? check this out [link](http://s24.postimg.org/5racwxdj9/Capture.png)

Comment: I followed what you did exactly and [this](http://snag.gy/404JO.jpg) is what happened.

Comment: That's weird. I have modified the code to remove the echo off which will help us to see the each steps, to diagnose the issue. Could you please do exactly what I have done [here](http://s24.postimg.org/6hn8ibztx/New_Picture.jpg)  and post the screenshot?

Comment: [Picture #1](http://snag.gy/0Dk5x.jpg), [Picture #2](http://snag.gy/0UK4Q.jpg), [Picture #3](http://snag.gy/W3wYL.jpg)

Comment: Well, Got the issue. you never said there are white space before `<string>` and also one of the line has only `<data>` in it. Give me the content of the xml file exactly (upload it somewhere or edit the question and update it with proper formatting.) and I will make the necessary changes.

Comment: Download it [here](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/5597b084)... Uncheck "Use our download manager and get recommended downloads" to download normally. Could you comment when you've downloaded it, I'd like to delete the link soon enough. Thanks

Comment: Nope. Checking your file. It is not possible to retrieve the string stored between <data> and </data> as it is not a single line and has multiple breaks. I could try to get the text between <string> </string>. Would you like me to proceed?

Comment: Aacini's answer works for the text between `<string>` and `</string>`. Sorry for not specifying, I'm a noob. Thanks for everything anyways.

Comment: No probs. Sorry I couldn't help to get your final answer, but I have modified the code to get the content between `<string> </string>`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /L "<string> <data>" theFile.xml') do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "line=!line:*<string>=!"
   set "line=!line:*<data>=!"
   for /F "delims=<" %%b in ("!line!") do echo %%b
)) > result.txt
```

Comment: Works perfectly at extracting what's between `<string>` tags, but doesn't extract what's between `<data>` tags.

Comment: how to use this if the XML file is in a single line?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) script:

```
call xpath.bat "xml.xml" "//data"
```