# Extracting xml tags using a batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, text-extraction

Using a batch file , I have to extract the values of two tags from a xml file and write them into a .txt file in the following format :

```
#- Automatic Package Update
----------

Myurl = https://someurl

Myrevision = 26498

----------
```

Here is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info>
<entry
   path="."
   revision="26498"
   kind="dir">
<url>https://someurl/Ramin</url>
<relative-url>^/</relative-url>
<repository>
<root>https://someurl/Ramin</root>
</repository>
<wc-info>
<wcroot-abspath>C:/Users/ramin</wcroot-abspath>
<schedule>normal</schedule>
<depth>infinity</depth>
</wc-info>
<commit
   revision="26498">
<author>ramin</author>
<date>2022-05-03T15:58:37.325680Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
</info>
```

what I have to do is to get the value of the tag "url" and write it in front of "Myurl = " and also get the value of the tag "revision" and write it in front of "Myrevision" and save the result in a .txt file.

Using the answer here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24944510/20053469 I managed to do this only for "url". I would like to know how to do this also for revision which is under the branch of "entry".

Comment: To put it in simple terms, PowerShell, PowerShell, PowerShell. Batch files were never designed for text manipulation, working with UTF-8 strings, or files containing problematic characters, _(`<` and `>`)_. PowerShell was, and it also has cmdlets specifically for handling XML. As an added note, there is more than one tag for `revision`, so we'd also require clarification on that.

Comment: If I use powershell , how can I do such thing? And about the Revision , as I mentioned at the end of my question , I need to extract the value for the revision under the "entry" tag. Thank you

Comment: On a general note, consider using conformant XML libraries and not treating XML as text manipulation. Specifically, for your need, consider XSLT which can transform XML to text and PowerShell can run XSLT. See demo (using [.Net's XslCompiledTransform Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform?view=net-7.0) which PowerShell can call): https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQX5xS/1.

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot. I will go and do some further investigation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important point first: you *should not* use Batch files to process .xml files because if the format of the .xml file changes in any way, the Batch file will stop working.

*However* if you understand this point and the required processing is not too complicated, you can solve your problem in a simple way via a Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "entry=" & set "Myrevision="
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=<=>/ " %%a in ('findstr "entry revision url" input.xml') do (
   if "%%a" == "entry" (
      set "entry=1"
   ) else if "%%a" == "revision" (
      if defined entry if not defined Myrevision set "Myrevision=%%~b"
   ) else if "%%a" == "url" (
      set "Myurl=%%b//%%c"
   )
)

(
   echo #- Automatic Package Update
   echo ----------
   echo/
   echo Myurl = %Myurl%
   echo/
   echo Myrevision = %Myrevision%
   echo/
   echo ----------
) > output.txt
```

The output of this program is *exactly the same* you requested...

Comment: This is exactly what I expected as the result. Thank you. No , the structure and the format of the xml file will remain the same. I could go on and write a python script for it , but In our case I decided to go with a batch file. Thanks again.

Comment: But isn't there a way to get the url as it is between the "url" tags? Because this way we are defining the format of the value of the url using the tokens. So let's say if the url goes bigger and bigger , we gotta go and manually increase the tokens and define the format of the url in : **set "Myurl=%%b//%%c"**

Comment: This is precisely what _" if the format of the .xml file changes in any way, the Batch file will stop working"_ means! Is possible to get the `%%~DPn` path of a token, but above code must be modified. If you would included several examples of the result you wanted with several different url paths, I would designed the Batch file accordingly since the very beginning...  **`:(`**

Comment: You still did a great job ,helped me a lot and I am thankful for that. I look up **%%~DPn** and see how I can fix and rewrite the script. Thanks again