# Extract text from XML file into a txt file with batch

Tags: batch-file

I have an XML file that I use for inventory and I just need to get some numbers out of the file and create a text file with the information in it.

Here is a sample of the XML file.

- LOCATION id="SP207-11" timeEntered="9/30/15 3:05:16 PM"         timeExited="9/30/15 3:10:06 PM">
- ITEMS>

  ITEM id="515 EE141332" />

  ITEM id="515 EE130004" />

  ITEM id="515 EE129298" />

And here is what I need it to look like.

SP207-11

515 EE141332

515 EE130004

515 EE129298

Comment: Looks, the formatting does appear properly, See here to edit http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: If it's valid, well-formed XML, you can use a PowerShell one-liner.  `powershell "([xml](gc xmlfile.xml)).SelectNodes(\"//*[@id]\") | %{ $_.id }"`

Answer (score 0):

If your XML is not `All on one line` :
You can make something like this :

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (test.txt) do (
  set $Val=%%a
  set $Val=!$Val:timeEntered=!
  set $Val=!$Val:/^>=!
  echo !$Val:"=!
)
```

Else take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196417/extracting-string-from-any-non-binary-file-irrespective-of-its-location-within-f)